# how to make a timer to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def choosePath():
    path = ""
    while path != "e" and path !="n":
        print('\nWhich way do you go (n, s, e, w):\n')
        t = Timer(1 * 1, timeout)
        t.start()
        answer = input(path)
        path = path.lower()
        if path =="e":
            station()
        elif path =="n":
            estate()
        elif path =="s":
            building()
        else:
            print("\nYou return the way you came are but are soon caught by Mansons and assimilated.\n")
        return path
```

I have received this code and want to add a timer that if answer isn't done with a certain amount of time it says gameover.

Answer (score 3):

You want the Timer class in the threading module.

```
import threading

t = threading.Timer(<delay in secs>, <callback>, [<function args>])
t.start()
```

If the user has selected an option in time call `t.cancel()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the timer outside of the while loop. There are also several ways to implement a timer, but this should work (I simplified it, you'll need to adjust it to your business logic)

```
import time

start_time = datetime.now()
max_time_allowed = 45
while path != "e" and path !="n":
    #Business logic here
    current_time= datetime.now()
    if current_time-start_time > max_time_allowed:
        return
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\oat.int\home$\acs\student\2015\15SrokaTy\Documents\Python Coding\IOT adventure - no one can survive..py", line 232, in <module>
    backstory()
  File "\\oat.int\home$\acs\student\2015\15SrokaTy\Documents\Python Coding\IOT adventure - no one can survive..py", line 23, in backstory
    time.sleep(0)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Comment: line 1 `from time import time` should just be `import time`, please update your post